# Best way to store/display data in angular

Tags: json, angular, xml

So I have a FAQ page which I have developed in angular and I have hardcoded all the data in a html file .I just wanted to know is there a better way of displaying the data like storing it in a **XML/JSON/TXT** file and read the file and display it or store the **XML/JSON/TXT** file in angular and read form it**(if storing it where to store it)**.

.Browsed for a few articles didn't find anything helpful ,any guidance will be appreciated. I am new to angular so just looking for some advice ,thanks in advance.

[image: FAQ-image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is static I recommend storing it in a JSON file inside your angular application under the assets folder.

You can then use Angular HttpClient to retrieve the content of the file.

In this example, the file is called 'data.json' and is stored under the 'assets' folder:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-component',
 templateUrl: './my-component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./my-component.css']
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 ngOnInit() {
   this.http.get('/assets/data.json').subscribe().then(data => console.log(data));
 }
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://jsonworld.com/demo/how-to-read-local-json-file-in-angular).

Comment: thanks for the response ,yes the data is static I have a lot of accordions and a lot of data in those accordions. Would that be an issue ? and is it a good practice to store in the assets folder ?

Comment: I don't think it would be an issue, as long as you intend to keep this JSON data static, else you should store it in a server.
The assets folder is a good place to store JSON/images/css. I recommend having a folder structure inside the assets folder so you can organize files with different types/purposes.

Comment: understood ,thank you for the response .Much appreciated